# NamedTuple, is the class being treated as a value

Tags: python, class, namedtuple

In the code below:

```
point=namedtuple('point','x y')
```

I am confused that a class is being treated as a value. As in when I do:

```
class point:
     ...
```

It creates a class object named point in the namespace, but not in the named tuple case.

And if that is the case, how is the value being identified by the interpreter? Like in

```
x=12; y=12;
```

`x` and `y` refer to the same value 12. 
If I do

```
point1=namedtuple('point','x y')
```

does it refer to the same class before?

Answer (score 5):

Classes are *just objects* in Python. `namedtuple()` returns a new class each time (the name is only used to set the `__name__` attribute). Calling `namedtuple()` multiple times with the same name will still create multiple unique class objects:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> point_one = namedtuple('point', 'x y')
>>> point_two = namedtuple('point', 'x y')
>>> point_one
<class '__main__.point'>
>>> point_one is point_two
False
```

You can create multiple Python classes with the `type()` function too:

```
 >>> point_first = type('point', (object,), {})
>>> point_second = type('point', (object,), {})
>>> point_first is point_second
False
```

or by nesting a `class` statement in a function:

```
def foo():
    class point:
        # ...
    return point
```

The only reason that a `class` statement at the top level of a module just creates one class is that Python treats modules as singletons; the code to create a module is executed just *once*, when importing it the first time (after which the result is stored in `sys.modules`).